# The target deployment path does not match the POM's expected path prefix

Tags: maven, artifactory

I have configured Jfrog Artifactory on a new server and have took a backup of the old repo and was trying to import that to the new server.

I am receiving the following error while I'm importing :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Failed to validate pom file: The target deployment path 'jcenter-cache/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.3.8.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.pom' 
does not match the POM's expected path prefix 'org/springframework/spring-beans/4.3.8.RELEASE'. 
Please verify your POM content for correctness and make sure the source path is a valid Maven repository root path.
```

The repository I created was a local and can import artefacts except the POM files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to deploy the exported repository name as part of your path in the local repository, and I will explain:

Artifactory has a protection mechanism that assists you in making sure that Maven would be able to work with your files. This is being done by making sure that the pom files are being deployed by their layout.

You should delete the files that you have imported to the local repository and start the import process again one layer down, so the `jcenter-cache` will not be part of the import path.